# How to compare (pairs of) images with convolutional DNN?

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing, paired-data

I have series of pictures of the same places, taken with the same cameras and I need to classify changes on pictures, like leaves fell, snow appeard, object appears disappears etc.

Which topology to choose for this?

First I though that I can just concatenate pairs of images side by side and pass it to DNN, like here

[image]

But I am confused with what will be happening in the middle? Will these regions produce noise?

Then I thought to stack images to form 2xN channel samples:

[image]

And also I thought about something like this:

[image]

Which topology is used for this kind of tasks?

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem myself. I have had recent luck with stacking the images and using 2x channels. This reduces the number of learned parameters in comparison to your last model, which is okay assuming that the features in one set of images are the same features as the second set of images.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar question as yours. My answer would be to stack the images. Here is how it works:

When you stuck the images, your image pairs will be treated as one image with multiple channels. For instance, if you stack two 3-channel images, your stacked image will be treated as one image with 6 channels.

You would probably feed your image pairs in a convolutional layer. For the first CNN layer, if you have a filter size of 4x4, your filters would have the shape of 4x4x6. 6 is the depth of the images (2x3 channels). This is how it works in pix2pix. You feed the fake image together with the conditioning image, these two images are stacked and a filter with a depth of the sum of these two images are used to perform the convolution in the discriminator.

I hope it helps.